# Call was rejected by callee PowerPoint Automation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, com, powerpoint, office-automation

I have a commandbar model which automates PowerPoint. I recently faced a strange problem that when PowerPoint is opened through my application, and the data is being loaded through my application to populate the menu.  If a user right clicks on PowerPoint I get the error message:

> Call was rejected by callee powerpoint

How do I resolve this?  I'm using Office 2003/2007 and VB.NET for office automation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this tutorial?:
[How to: Fix 'Application is Busy' and 'Call was Rejected By Callee' Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx)

> To fix errors:
>     1. Add the following class to your application.
>     2. Add a COM reference to `Microsoft Development Environment 8.0.` This adds references to `EnvDTE` and `EnvDTE80` to your solution.
>     3. In the code, create an instance of `EnvDTE80`, as outlined in the following example.
>     4. Call `Message.Register` to handle thread errors.
>     5. Call your automation code as usual.
>     6. When your automation code is finished, call `Message.Revoke` to remove the thread error handlers.