# COM Exception - Call was rejected by callee and The runtime has encountered a fatal error

Tags: vb.net, com, ms-word

In my VB.NET application I have a class called Letter. In the constructor of the Letter class I initialize new word.application object.

```
Sub New()
    _application = New Word.Application
End Sub
```

Recently I started to get a COM exception/error - Call was rejected by callee. After doing my research I have implemented the solution suggested in the following link:

[Call was rejected by callee PowerPoint Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379334/call-was-rejected-by-callee-powerpoint-automation)

After the implementation I have the following code:

```
Sub New()
    MessageFilterAPI.RegisterMessageFilter()
    _application = New Word.Application
    MessageFilterAPI.RevokeMessageFilter()
End Sub
```

This stopped error appearing on my machine (dev environment), but other machine where the software is installed still gets the error. Full exception message:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

When debugging on the initializing line `_application = New Word.Application` program completely crashes and freezes with the following exception:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x74444ba1, on thread 0x5e48. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening? This code hasn't been changed in years and it suddenly became an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually memory issues or corrupted installation. So I'll try to reinstall Office and run "memtest86" to test memory on machine, that shows 0xc0000005 error

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to right direction. I was initializing word application object couple of times in the loop and not disposing/closing it properly. I had lots of them opened and running in the background (checked task manager). After I closed down all opened word processes and sorted outy code, issue was solved.